# ColdFusion cflocation to new tab

Tags: coldfusion, cflocation

How can I use cflocation to open new tab?

I submit a form, then it should open a new tab and redirect the original page. Is it possible?

```
<cfform ACTION="./test.cfm" METHOD=POST>
```

Then in the test.cfm

```
    <!-- Some database update here -->

<!--- I would like to open it in new tab --->
<cflocation url="newTab.cfm" addtoken="false">

<!--- Then refirect the current page to new link --->
<cflocation url="redirect.cfm" addtoken="false">
```

Is it possible to be done?

Thanks

Comment: No, the server has no control over the client.

Comment: Thanks. If you gave me a negative point for the question. Could you tell me why?

Comment: Off topic, but I would recommend staying away from `cfform`. https://static.raymondcamden.com/cfuitherightway/index.html

Comment: Why off topic??

Comment: "Why off topic??" It's not directly related to your question, but good information to know about cfform.

Answer (score 4):

The closest you can get is

```
<cfform ACTION="./test.cfm" METHOD=POST target="_blank"
    onsubmit="window.location('redirect.cfm')">
```

The user's browers might go into a new tab.

**Per Dan**

The rest of this equation is

```
onsubmit="window.location('redirect.cfm')"
```

Comment: Thanks... The problem is that I need to open a new tab with an URL and refresh/submit the form with another URL

Comment: Sound awfully convoluted.  Maybe if you step back and look at the overall objective, you will think of an easier way to achieve it.

Comment: As mentioned in earlier comments, those kind of actions require client side code - not server side (cflocation), but agreed it does sound convoluted...